# CMAKE Required header sys/stat.h not found

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to configure the bcl2fastq program that uses CMake.  I found the line that triggers this error message

```
file:bcl2fastq/src/cmake/cxxConfigure.cmake
############## content ####################
..... # ignoring many lines
bcl2fastq_find_header_or_die(HAVE_SYS_STAT_H  sys/stat.h)
......# more lines following
```

error message:

```
-- time.h found as /usr/include/time.h
-- unistd.h found as /usr/include/unistd.h
CMake Error at cmake/macros.cmake:80 (message):
  Required header sys/stat.h not found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/cxxConfigure.cmake:41 (bcl2fastq_find_header_or_die)
  cxx/CMakeLists.txt:34 (include)
```

On my system, the `sys/stat.h` is located in

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

In the past, I add a symbolic link in `/usr/include` to the `sys/stat.h`, which patched the problem. Can someone suggest a better method by modifying the CMake files?

Digging deeper, I found the `macros.cmake` file in the same directory as `cxxConfigure.cmake` contains the macro definition:

```
#   
# Macro to find libraries, with support for static-only search
#
macro(bcl2fastq_find_header_or_die variable file)
find_file(${variable} ${file} HINTS ENV C_INCLUDE_PATH ENV CPATH ENV CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH)
if    (${variable})
    message(STATUS "${file} found as ${${variable}}")
else  (${variable})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Required header ${file} not found.")
endif (${variable})
endmacro(bcl2fastq_find_header_or_die)
```

Then I did the following:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

After that, CMake seems to be happy. Not sure this is the proper way to handle this problem.

Comment: The standard location of `stat.h` on Unix systems is in `/usr/include/sys`. Seems like there's a problem with your installation if it's not located there.

Comment: As the header is installed in a non-standard location, you have to add the folder containing the header to the cmake search path.

Comment: My system is ubuntu 16.  The ubuntu maintainers decided to put there.  This problem is specific to all users of ubuntu.

Comment: What's your version of CMake? Maybe this is already fixed.

Comment: cmake version 3.5.1, As we are talking, the current cmake is 3.10.2 could be my old version. I will try to upgrade cmake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exporting the environment variable like

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

is one use.

Moreover, according to the [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html) on the `find_path` command, `PATHS` should be used over `HINTS` for hard-coded guesses, which means modifying `macros.cmake` like this

```
find_file([...] PATHS /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu)
```

is more appropriate. For more flexibility, this could be combined with a `PATHS ENV` variable, too. The use of `PATHS` vs `HINTS` has also been asked in the CMake mailing list [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-October/040460.html), but the explanation didn't offer much more than the documentation entry.

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder called sys in /usr/include.

Copied over the stat.h into that folder and ran the make command again. The bcl2fastq build completed without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Write `<sys/stat.h>` instead of `<stat.h>` in your code.